# ProGuard not working in my app

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to protect my apk file with ProGuard but I got errors.

```
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnGetPlaybackPositionListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$2: can't find superclass or interface android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2: can't find referenced method 'int getCapabilities()' in library class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void startActivity(android.content.Intent,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.content.Context
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.app.Activity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void finishAffinity()' in library class android.app.Activity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompatJB: can't find referenced class android.app.ActivityOptions
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompatJB: can't find referenced class android.app.ActivityOptions
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompatJB: can't find referenced class android.app.ActivityOptions
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompatJB: can't find referenced class android.app.ActivityOptions
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompatJB: can't find referenced class android.app.ActivityOptions
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getParentActivityIntent()' in library class android.app.Activity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(android.content.Intent)' in library class android.app.Activity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean navigateUpTo(android.content.Intent)' in library class android.app.Activity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB: can't find referenced field 'java.lang.String parentActivityName' in library class android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setSubText(java.lang.CharSequence)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setUsesChronometer(boolean)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setPriority(int)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(int,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification build()' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$InboxStyle
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.ShareCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String escapeHtml(java.lang.CharSequence)' in library class android.text.Html
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilderJellybean: can't find referenced method 'android.app.PendingIntent getActivities(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent[],int,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.app.PendingIntent
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatJellybean: can't find referenced method 'void startActivities(android.content.Intent[],android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.content.Context
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.content.IntentCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.Intent
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced class android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced class android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced class android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.hardware.display.DisplayManagerJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced class android.hardware.display.DisplayManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void addOnWindowAttachListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener)' in library class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener)' in library class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnWindowAttachListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener)' in library class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener)' in library class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void setOnGetPlaybackPositionListener(android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnGetPlaybackPositionListener)' in library class android.media.RemoteControlClient
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener)' in library class android.media.RemoteControlClient
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.media.AudioManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void setPlaybackState(int,long,float)' in library class android.media.RemoteControlClient
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced method 'void unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.media.AudioManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnGetPlaybackPositionListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$1: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$2: can't find referenced class android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in library class android.net.ConnectivityManager
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider getAccessibilityNodeProvider(android.view.View)' in library class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAccessibilityAction(android.view.View,int,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.GravityCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void apply(int,int,int,android.graphics.Rect,android.graphics.Rect,int)' in library class android.view.Gravity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.GravityCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void apply(int,int,int,android.graphics.Rect,int,int,android.graphics.Rect,int)' in library class android.view.Gravity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.GravityCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void applyDisplay(int,android.graphics.Rect,android.graphics.Rect,int)' in library class android.view.Gravity
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getMarginStart()' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getMarginEnd()' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setMarginStart(int)' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setMarginEnd(int)' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'boolean isMarginRelative()' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getLayoutDirection()' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLayoutDirection(int)' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.MarginLayoutParamsCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void resolveLayoutDirection(int)' in library class android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean hasTransientState()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void setHasTransientState(boolean)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postInvalidateOnAnimation()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postOnAnimation(java.lang.Runnable)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void postOnAnimationDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,long)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'int getImportantForAccessibility()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'void setImportantForAccessibility(int)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAccessibilityAction(int,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeProvider getAccessibilityNodeProvider()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJB: can't find referenced method 'android.view.ViewParent getParentForAccessibility()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getLabelFor()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLabelFor(int)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLayerPaint(android.graphics.Paint)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getLayoutDirection()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatJellybeanMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setLayoutDirection(int)' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void addChild(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setSource(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isVisibleToUser()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setVisibleToUser(boolean)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean performAction(int,android.os.Bundle)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setMovementGranularities(int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'int getMovementGranularities()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo obtain(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo findFocus(int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo focusSearch(int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setParent(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAccessibilityFocused()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setAccessibilityFocused(boolean)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getMaxScrollX()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced method 'int getMaxScrollY()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setMaxScrollX(int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1: can't find referenced method 'void setMaxScrollY(int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatJellyBean: can't find referenced method 'void setSource(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in library class android.view.View
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in library class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: there were 49 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Warning: there were 77 unresolved references to library class members.
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          You probably need to update the library versions.
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
[2013-08-14 12:21:41 - LookAround] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

and my proguard-project.txt

```
    -libraryjars /libs/android-support-v4.jar
    -libraryjars C:/Users/User/workspace/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
   -dontoptimize
   -dontpreverify
   -dontwarn android.support.**
   -verbose

    -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
    -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
    -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
    -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
    -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
    -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
    -keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
    -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

    -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

    -keep class android.support.v4.media.** { *; }
    -keep interface android.support.v4.media.** { *; }

    -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
      void set*(***);
      *** get*();
    }

    -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static *** d(...);
        public static *** v(...);
        public static *** w(...);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native <methods>;
    }


    -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context);
    }
    -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }
    -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    }

    #Maintain enums
    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }

    #To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
    }

    #Keep the R
    -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
        public static <fields>;
    }
```

Also I am using GoogleMap V2 in my application

Answer (score 15):

As indicated by the link to the [ProGuard Troubleshooting page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember) in your console log, you should change the target in `project.properties` to a target that contains the missing classes. In this case: "android-18" or maybe "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18".

You can still specify a different minSdkVersion in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

You should *not* specify any -libraryjars options, since the Android build process already specifies those options for you -- you'll just see warnings about duplicate classes now. In fact, the Android build process specifies most other options for you as well.

Answer (score 12):

I got this after update of Android Support Library to rev.18. Fixed it by adding:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

to ProGuard configuration file.

Comment: nothing change i still have this problems


I am using GoogleAPIs Level 14 and Android Support Library rev.18

Comment: As you can see at the end of warning list there are 2 warnings for Google Maps. I don't know what implications could have but try the same with GMS...
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.**

Comment: i know i have 2 warning and tried all of this before but still nothing change. my MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener

Comment: +1 The best solution, as it works fine and does not require you to update the target SDK level.

Answer (score 1):

(I use MOTODEV Studio 4.1 and first enable proguard in menu "MOTODEV")

**Method one: Add the first line to your proguard.cfg file directly, maybe the second line is needed.**

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

**Another way: according the proguard-project.txt instruction to remove "#" before ${sdk.dir} in project.properties, then add the above two lines in proguard-project.txt**