# Proguard returned with error code 1, error can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, proguard

I am receiving this exception while creation of signed apk of my application.

```
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced method 'void setShowsDialog(boolean)' in class com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.SupportErrorDialogFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.api.d: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.google.android.gms.common.api.d
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.h: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gz: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gz: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gz: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gz: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.he: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.he: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$a: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$b: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment$b: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment$c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment$c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment$c: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: there were 150 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2017-04-13 02:47:21 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

the warning say  if Alternatively, you may have to specify the option -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

and here is my proguard.cfg

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: resolve by add -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
on proguard.cfg

Answer (score 3):

this is what i do in my proguard for android support

```
#########--------Android Support--------#########
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

As indicated by the link to the [ProGuard Troubleshooting page](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedlibraryclassmember) in your console log, you should change the target in project.properties to a target that contains the missing classes. In this case: "android-18" or maybe "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18".

You can still specify a different minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml.

You should not specify any -libraryjars options, since the Android build process already specifies those options for you -- you'll just see warnings about duplicate classes now. In fact, the Android build process specifies most other options for you as well.

source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229561/proguard-not-working-in-my-app)

Comment: if its not working, it may be problem with your gradle.. check your android version, minSdkVersion, android dependencies if setup correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try add this line to your proguard file:

`-dontwarn android.support.v4.**`

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same error? @SiriusKuddo

Comment: yes, but after Im added -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
warning error is gone

Comment: Good job! @SiriusKuddo