# Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.FlowUtils

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui, firebase-util

When in try to run in release mode it is showing below error's and warning. How to solve this problem?

```
 Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.RegisterEmailFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context requireContext()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.RegisterEmailFragment
    Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
    Warning:com.afollestad.materialdialogs.DialogInit: can't find referenced class me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.IndeterminateProgressDrawable
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context requireContext()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity requireActivity()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.RegisterEmailFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity requireActivity()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.RegisterEmailFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context requireContext()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SubmitConfirmationCodeFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity requireActivity()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SubmitConfirmationCodeFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SubmitConfirmationCodeFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context requireContext()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SubmitConfirmationCodeFragment
    Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.FlowUtils: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity requireActivity()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.FragmentBase
    Warning:there were 8 unresolved references to program class members.
    Warning:there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > Job failed, see logs for details
```

I am using  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:+'

Comment: Update the post with your class file where you implemented firebase UI. Warning alone can't help us to trance it

Comment: i removed all code and now it is only avalable in build.gradel

Comment: implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:+

Comment: now i am removed from build.gradel and trying to run

Comment: it is woking now , after removed firebase ui

Answer (score 0):

solved few warning

```
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.FlowUtils.**
```

But again issue

```
Warning:com.firebase.ui.auth.util.ui.FlowUtils: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity requireActivity()' in program class com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.FragmentBase
```

Comment: How about this for the other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382069/4409113 ?